# Combining Multiple Dictionaries into One DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have three dictionaries we'll call: W, E, T

The Dictionaries look like:

```
W = {'name': [1, 2, 3], 'prob': [0.2, 0.3, 0.5], 'div': [5, 3, 2], 'pos':[2, 1, 3]}
E = {'name': [[1,2], [2,1], [1, 3], [2, 3]], 'prob': [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4], 'div': [3, 5, 10, 2.5], 'pos':[[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3]]}
T = {'name': [[1,2,3], [2,1,3], [3,1,2]], 'prob': [0.3, 0.02, 0.68], 'div': [3, 50, 1.5], 'pos':[[2,1,3], [1,2,3], [3, 2, 1]]}
```

I'm not sure how to combine the three into one DF that looks like:

```
name    prob   div   pos
1        0.2    5     2
2        0.3    3     1
3        0.5    2     3
[1,2]    0.3    3     [2, 1]
[2,1]    0.2    5     [1, 2]
[1,3]    0.1    10    [2, 3]
[2,3]    0.4    2.5   [1, 3]
[1,2,3]  0.3    3     [2, 1, 3]
[2,1,3]  0.02   50    [1, 2, 3]
[3,1,2]  0.68   1.5   [3, 2, 1]
```

I tried using

```
mydicts = [W,E,T]

pd.DataFrame(mydicts)
Out[1162]: 
                                name                  prob              div  \
0                          [1, 2, 3]       [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]        [5, 3, 2]   
1   [[1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 3]]  [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]  [3, 5, 10, 2.5]   
2  [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2]]     [0.3, 0.02, 0.68]     [3, 50, 1.5]   

                                 pos  
0                          [2, 1, 3]  
1   [[2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3]]  
2  [[2, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
```

But this just seemed to nest the dictionary values into the columns without separating them into rows.

Comment: use `concat` and a list comp `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d) for d in [W,E,T]],0)` use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` to read a dictionary, it has certain arguments to let you specify the axis to read your object by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(W), pd.DataFrame(E), pd.DataFrame(T)])
```